# Reformatting tables

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have the following type of tables:

```
ID   date     DailyFlow
a 1972-01-01 17.0265761797993
b 1972-01-02 17.200476457399
c 1972-01-03 17.2926436045271
d 1972-01-04 17.3900277599829
e 1972-01-05 17.5987080931028
f 1972-01-06 17.6334881486229
g 1972-01-07 17.7030482596626
...
```

I would like to reformat them as follow:

```
YYYY    DDD sim
1972    1   17.0265761797993
1972    2   17.200476457399
1972    3   17.2926436045271
1972    4   17.3900277599829
1972    5   17.5987080931028
1972    6   17.6334881486229
1972    7   17.7030482596626
1972    8   17.7204382874227
```

The first row is contained in the tables. The files are plain-text (*.txt) with a "tab" separator. The ID column is a dummy one that I would like to get rid of it! In my desired output the numbers (1,2,3,...) on the DDD column shall fit with the day of the corresponding years.

Does anyone as any idea about how to do that (using bash)? Thanks!

Comment: @Rinzwind - Yes sorry I should have been more explicit. The output values shall remain the same, but the output must have the same frame as the second example. I will re-edit my question

Comment: Where is the table stored? DBMS? Which? Or in a plain-text file? Is the first row actually in the file? How are columns separated? Tabs?

Comment: Also "using bash"; would you accept a `sed` / `awk` / `perl` solution to be run in `bash`?

Comment: @kos - Yes definitely, I accept all kind of solution that can be run in bash! The table are plain-text file. The first row is within the file and columns have a "tab" seperation. I will re-edit my question again ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind - You´re right! By bash I mean the command line

Comment: Steve, is the ID coincidentally similar to the day number or is it by definition?

Comment: @JacobVlijm - The ID is just a dummy column that I want to get rid of it!

Comment: @Rinzwind Just to be safe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` for parsing and `date` to format the date, what else **;)**

```
awk 'BEGIN {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n","YYYY","DDD","sim"} NR != 1 {system("date -d \""$2"\" +\"%Y\t%-d\t"$3"\"")}' your_file
```

To show the day of the year (using `%j` instead of `%d` or better `%-j` instead of `%-d`, the `-` avoids leading `0`)

```
awk 'BEGIN {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n","YYYY","DDD","sim"} NR != 1 {system("date -d \""$2"\" +\"%Y\t%-j\t"$3"\"")}' your_file
```

---

*Example*

The input file

```
% cat foo
ID   date     DailyFlow
a 1972-01-01 17.0265761797993
b 1972-01-02 17.200476457399
c 1972-01-03 17.2926436045271
d 1972-01-04 17.3900277599829
e 1972-01-05 17.5987080931028
f 1972-01-06 17.6334881486229
g 1972-01-07 17.7030482596626
h 1972-02-01 17.7030482596626
i 1972-02-02 17.7030482596626
```

The output (with the day of the month)

```
% awk 'BEGIN {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n","YYYY","DDD","sim"} NR != 1 {system("date -d \""$2"\" +\"%Y\t%-d\t"$3"\"")}' foo
YYYY    DDD sim
1972    1   17.0265761797993
1972    2   17.200476457399
1972    3   17.2926436045271
1972    4   17.3900277599829
1972    5   17.5987080931028
1972    6   17.6334881486229
1972    7   17.7030482596626
1972    1   17.7030482596626
1972    2   17.7030482596626
```

The output (with the day of the year)

```
% awk 'BEGIN {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n","YYYY","DDD","sim"} NR != 1 {system("date -d \""$2"\" +\"%Y\t%-j\t"$3"\"")}' foo
YYYY    DDD sim
1972    1   17.0265761797993
1972    2   17.200476457399
1972    3   17.2926436045271
1972    4   17.3900277599829
1972    5   17.5987080931028
1972    6   17.6334881486229
1972    7   17.7030482596626
1972    32  17.7030482596626
1972    33  17.7030482596626
```

Comment: Works like a charm! However the day (column) now fits the month and the the years (I basically searched for a day column going from 1 to 365). Moreover too bad that I can just accept one answer!

Comment: +1 for the [third victim](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661332/reformatting-tables#comment952518_661353) ;)

Comment: The output is wrong in my answer?

Comment: No everything is just super fine! I don´t want to make any further victims! Thank you very much!

Comment: No it's ok apparently, but the problem is the `DDD` column should be the number of the day, not the `ID`'s value. Both me and chaos fell for that already

Comment: @steve improved my answer

Comment: And an additionally example.

Comment: @A.B - Thank you so much! It´s now exactly what I was searching for (is there no way to accept two answer?)

Comment: @A.B. :D  Both upvoted!

Comment: @kos I've never used the IDs.

Comment: I assumed you were, since OP stated that, then grats, you were the only one not falling for that ;)

Answer (score 7):

<del>This would have been a job for `awk`, but the replacement in the second column would have required `gensub` and hence `gawk`, which is not installed by default, so</del> I ended up with a `sed` solution:

```
sed -i.bak 's/[^\t]*\t\([^-]*\)-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9]\([0-9]\)[^\t]*\t\([^\t]*\)/\1\t\2\t\3/' infile
```

Or, shortened using EREs (thanks to user1598390):

```
sed -E -i.bak 's/.*([0-9]{4})-[0-9]{2}-([0-9]{2})(.*)/\1\t\2\3/' infile
```

- `-i.bak`: processes the file in place, backing up the original file to `infile.bak`

`sed` command breakdown:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution;
- `/`: starts the pattern
- `[^\t]*`: matches any number of any character not `\t`;
- `\t`: matches a `\t` character
- `\(`: starts the first capturing group
- `[^-]*`: matches any number of any character not `-`;
- `\)`: stops the first capturing group
- `-`: matches a `-` character
- `[0-9]`: matches any digit
- `[0-9]`: matches any digit
- `-`: matches a `-` character
- `[0-9]`: matches any digit
- `\(`: starts the second capturing group
- `[0-9]`: matches any digit
- `\)`: stops the second capturing group
- `[^\t]*`: matches any number of any character not `\t`;
- `\t`: matches a `\t` character
- `\(`: starts the third capturing group
- `[^\t]*`: matches any number of any character not `\t`;
- `\)`: stops the third capturing group
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `\1`: backreference replaced with the first capturing group
- `\2`: backreference replaced with the second capturing group
- `\3`: backreference replaced with the third capturing group
- `/`: stops the replacement string / starts the modifiers

Output for the sample file:

```
user@debian ~/tmp % cat infile 
a   1972-01-01  17.0265761797993
b   1972-01-02  17.200476457399
c   1972-01-03  17.2926436045271
d   1972-01-04  17.3900277599829
e   1972-01-05  17.5987080931028
f   1972-01-06  17.6334881486229
g   1972-01-07  17.7030482596626
user@debian ~/tmp % sed 's/[^\t]*\t\([^-]*\)-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9]\([0-9]\)[^\t]*\t\([^\t]*\)/\1\t\2\t\3/' infile
1972    1   17.0265761797993
1972    2   17.200476457399
1972    3   17.2926436045271
1972    4   17.3900277599829
1972    5   17.5987080931028
1972    6   17.6334881486229
1972    7   17.7030482596626
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and all the attached explanation! I am a novice and thanks to that I am learning a lot! Unfortunately when I use this command (assuming my input file is called "infile.txt")     [sed -i.bak 's/\([^\t]*\)\t\([^-]*\)[^\t]*\t\([^\t]*\)/\2\t\1\t\3/' infile.txt]  the input file just remain the same and the created *.bak is the same as the input file. I am sure that I am missing something!

Comment: @steve Probably your file differs slightly from the example you posted, for example even a space (or a random tabulation) at the end of each line would break it. Are you sure there's nothing at the end of the lines? However chaos' answer is *way* more elegant, as `awk` *is* the tool for this

Comment: I did a stupid mistake, my fault! Thank you so much for your help and teaching lessons at the same time ;)

Comment: @steve No problem :) Wait for chaos to update his answer tough, because as of now (as the first version of my answer) it doesn't change the output the second column based on the day, but on the ID, which [looks like](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661332/reformatting-tables/661353?noredirect=1#comment952456_661332) it's not what you want

Comment: Yes you´re right! The day is fitting the ID and I would like that the day fit with the corresponding days of the corresponding years!

Comment: @steve Can you point this out in the question? There are 2 victims already :|

Comment: Sorry! I update the question right now!

Comment: Victory, `date` is the better way =)

Comment: @A.B. Not really, [`awk` is](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661332/reformatting-tables/661353?noredirect=1#comment952508_661353) (last statement) ;)

Comment: For the day of the year? 1…365?

Comment: @A.B. and leapyears? >:-D

Comment: @Rinzwind `date` never fails =)

Comment: Great solution. I made it shorter and more legible: `sed -E -i.bak 's/^.*([0-9]{4})-[0-9]{2}-([0-9]{2}) (.*)$/\1\t\2\t\3/g' infile`

Comment: @user1598390 Actually I used BREs intentionally at first (no particularly good reason to do so tough). Thanks for the suggestion, I've adapted it a bit and added it to the post

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "YYYY\tDDD\tsim"} NR!=1{printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",substr($2,0,5),$1,$3}' file
```

Explanation

1. The `BEGIN{}` part formats the header line.
2. `NR!=1` omits the header line of your file
3. `printf()` formats the output
4. `substr($2,0,5)` removes the day and month from the date

The output looks:

```
YYYY    DDD     sim
1972    1       17.0265761797993
1972    2       17.200476457399
1972    3       17.2926436045271
1972    4       17.3900277599829
1972    5       17.5987080931028
1972    6       17.6334881486229
1972    7       17.7030482596626
```

Comment: Indeed, `substr`. And anyway way better than my answer. The only problem is [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661332/reformatting-tables/661353?noredirect=1#comment952456_661332) and the comment below, which I also didn't see at first :|

Answer (score 1):

Using only `bash` :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
printf "YYYY\tDDD\tsim\n"
while IFS=$'\t' read -r first second third; do
    day="$(date --date="$second" '+%j')"
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "${second%%-*}" "${day##*(0)}" "${third}"
done < <(tail -n +2 foo.txt)
```

- We are reading each line of the input file starting from second line and putting tab separated portions as variable `first`, `second` and `third` successively
- Then we are using `bash` parameter expansion to get our desired output pattern. Read about parameter expansion from [GNU doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).
- `extglob` is used to remove the padded zeroes from days.

**Example :**

**Input :**

```
ID  date        DailyFlow
a   1972-01-01  17.0265761797993
b   1972-01-02  17.200476457399
c   1972-01-03  17.2926436045271
d   1972-01-04  17.3900277599829
e   1972-01-05  17.5987080931028
f   1972-01-06  17.6334881486229
g   1972-01-07  17.7030482596626
h   1972-02-01  17.7030482596626
i   1972-02-02  17.7030482596626
```

**Output :**

```
YYYY    DDD   sim
1972    1     17.0265761797993
1972    2     17.200476457399
1972    3     17.2926436045271
1972    4     17.3900277599829
1972    5     17.5987080931028
1972    6     17.6334881486229
1972    7     17.7030482596626
1972    32    17.7030482596626
1972    33    17.7030482596626
```

Comment: o_O my output is empty?

Comment: @A.B. ummm...dont know why..working for me..is your input tab separated ?

Comment: No, that was my problem. :)

Comment: And what is `23`? The day of the year?

Comment: @A.B. `23` is from my addition..it is the day extracted from `1972-01-23`..

Comment: OP needs the day of the year ;) You need some `date` magic.

Comment: @A.B. yeah..that is the day..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26988/discussion-between-a-b-and-heemayl).

Comment: Now it's a correct answer :) +1